# To build a 3D Plotly bar chart in R

Tags: r, plotly, r-markdown, ggplotly

Say we have the following dataframe:

```
customer_type    tier1   tier2  tier3
Sporadic         35      8      3
Repeater         22      12     11
Loyal            2       15     12
```

My aim is to translate this table into a three-dimensional bar plot which will take the column names and the values of `customer_type` field as `x` and `y` axes, while the height of each bar would be determined by the numerical values available on the table.

How should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a 3D histogram with Plotly in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64479652/how-to-make-a-3d-histogram-with-plotly-in-r)